# Suspicious App Store purchase emails

Tags: apple-id

I have recently bought a new iPad. I’ve had the old one stripped of all my info.

I keep getting emails from App Store stating ‘ payment receipt from Apple’ (in US dollars), different amounts every time. I haven’t bought anything, I’ve checked my bank account (there’s no change)have removed my bank details and changed my Apple password.

Could this be a scam or hack??

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to [check your purchase history](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204088).

There are some other things that can identify the email:

Genuine emails will contain your billing address:

> Genuine purchase receipts—from purchases in the App Store, iTunes Store, iBooks Store, or Apple Music—include your current billing address, which scammers are unlikely to have.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201679

You should report the email to reportphishing@apple.com

> If you receive what you believe to be a phishing email that's designed to look like it’s from Apple, please send it to reportphishing@apple.com.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204759

Importantly don’t open any attachments just in case, change your Apple ID password like you’ve already done and report the email immediately. You can also block the email.